# I'm running Ubuntu notebook on a USB drive with 1GB persistence. Where are my XAMPP files?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, xampp, persistent

I just began running Ubuntu Notebook on my 2GB USB stick, with 1GB persistence. After I installed XAMPP, I rebooted to make sure the persistence was working. It worked!

My XAMPP installation worked, and it comes up when I type localhost into the browser. The sample apps work, including the ones using MySQL. But I can't find the application files! I am used to the vast labyrinth of files in Windows Explorer, and looking through 'Files and Folders' in GNOME, there seem to only be 7 or 8 folders in the entire OS? What is really  going on here? I looked through them all and where is XAMPP?

When I code PHP with a WAMP stack, all the .php files go in the 'WWW folder'
What is the Linux equivalent of the WWW folder?

Comment: how did you install XAMPP?  there doesn't appear to be an official *xampp* package in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux equivalent of the WWW folder is usually in `/var/www`. All application files used to run the servers will be located scattered across several different directories. It's quite normal that a linux system only has about 8 directories in its root. It's all it needs.

Comment: XAMPP runs fine, but there is no XAMPP folder, no var/www folder, no otf directory on my computer apparently

Comment: try running the `find index.php` command from the root... it might offer a clue.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question.

> When I code PHP with a WAMP stack, all
>   the .php files go in the 'WWW folder'
>   What is the Linux equivalent of the
>   WWW folder?

In Ubuntu the 'default' location for the www folder is `/var/www`

Edit: For your first question `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`

Generally programs will install in 1 of 2 locations `/bin/` or `/sbin/`. Now that isn't always true tho. One place to check would be `/etc/` for a conf folder or file.

But a quick google shows me that xampp installs, if you follow the directions on their website, to the `/opt/` directory.

Comment: I followed the directions exactly. I know what folders im supposed to go to. I dont have any access to any system or program files, period.

Answer (score 0):

Check /opt/lampp :)
the linux equivalent of WWW folder is the /var/www folder but if you are using XAMPP it will be /opt/lampp/htdocs. I posted an answer to another one of your questions which is the same. Here it is -> https://superuser.com/questions/151501/i-installed-xampp-on-ubuntu-and-its-running-without-any-of-its-files/151505#151505

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410

> Location of files and uploading
>
> XAMPP by default uses
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs as the root web
>   directory. The easiest way to start
>   working on files is to link a folder
>   in your home directory into this
>   directory. My user name is peter so I
>   have /home/peter/public_html linked to
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/peter. So if I
>   navigate to http: //localhost/peter/ I
>   get a listing of all the files/folders
>   in that directory. (As long is there
>   isn't a index.php/html/etc file) To
>   set this up, run in a terminal:
>
> 1. Make public_html directory in home directory:
>        Code:
>
>    mkdir ~/public_html
> 2. Link to /opt/lampp/htdocs
>        Code:
>
>    sudo ln -s ~/public_html /opt/lampp/htdocs/$USER
>
> Now any files and folders you place in
>   ~/public_html will be published to
>   your personal webserver.
>
> Bookmark http ://localhost/username to
>   make this easy to access.